# How get array element from list some object

Tags: c#, linq

```
public class Ex
{
   public string example1{get;set;}
   public string example2{get;set;}
   public Test test{get;set;}
}    

public class Test
{
   public string example3 {get;set;}
 public long[] arrayLong{get;set;}
}
```

I have List listEx for example 10 elements. How get arraylong?

```
long[] result = listEx.Select( x=> x.Test.Select(y =>y.arrayLong)).ToArray();
```

I need only long[] how parse it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `SelectMany` function, which will "flatten" collection of collections to one collection.

```
var result = listEx.SelectMany(ex => ex.Test.Select(test => test.arrayLong)).ToArray();
```

From MSDN: [Enumerable.SelectMany Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx#Examples)

Answer (score 1):

You should use SelectMany

```
var outresult = listEx.SelectMany(t => t.Test.Select(s => s.arrayLong)).ToArray();
```